# Using auto layout to adjust label position based on conditional.

Tags: ios, swift

I have two labels that have are arranged one on top of another. Both of these are in a UITableViewCell :

[image: Label arrangement - one on top of another]

I would like to have a statement that does the following:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 {
    //Remove the bottom label and center the top label vertically in the cell
}

if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 {
    //Keep both labels one on top of the other
}
```

These have been created in a .xib file and are loaded into a table view. I would like to use auto layout for this, and I know that I need to use a few outlets to get this working. Any ideas on how this might done?

Comment: If you can target >= iOS9 then use a `UIStackView` for this.

Comment: You can have both the main bottom constraint and the centerY constraint in the storyboard on your UILabels; Then connect these constraints to your cell class with IBOutlets. After you can enable / disable these constraints as you want

Comment: @MikePollard is right, you can set both labels in a stackView, center the stackView with constraints, and hide/unhide the second label

Comment: @javiazo i'm unable to target my app for ios9 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func autolayout()
{

    if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 {
        //Remove the bottom label and center the top label vertically in the cell
        bottomLbl.hidden=true
        self.constrainToplbl_top.constant = 20  

    }

    if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 {
        //Keep both labels one on top of the other
        self.constrainToplbl_top.constant = 24
        self.constrainbottomlbl_top.constant = 2



    }
       self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Do not copy the code because it may cause compilation/syntax error

```
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 {
    //Remove the bottom label and center the top label vertically in the cell

    cell.lbl2.hidden = true
    cell.constCenter.constant = -cell.lbl2.frame.size.height/2
   // cell.constCenter obj of Label 1 center constraint below image display
}

if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 {
   //Keep both labels one on top of the other
    cell.lbl2.hidden = false
    cell.constCenter.constant = 0
  //by default it is like so no need to do anything
}
```

[image][image]

[image]

// Please discard image in below screen shot

Answer (score 0):

you add 3 `UILabels` (topLbl,centerLbl,bottomLbl) in cell, then just hide and show labels that you need to display

```
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 {
    //Remove the bottom label and center the top label vertically in the cell
    topLbl.hidden=true
    centerLbl.hidden=false
    bottomLbl.hidden=true
}

if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 {
    //Keep both labels one on top of the other
    topLbl.hidden=false
    centerLbl.hidden=true
    bottomLbl.hidden=false
}
```